# Reading over inbox, I get error #298

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I developed a app to read over someones inbox for keywords. If found to give them a score. It worked fine for awhile however now it does not. WHen I try to manually put in the information into the graph api (https://graph.facebook.com/(id)//threads?access_token=(token)) I get this error:

{
   "error": {
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "message": "(#298) You must be a developer of the application"
   }
}

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Why would anyone downvote this? I have the exakt same problem with a out-of-the-box fresh application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your application got disabled, potentially for violating the terms of service. I would contact the Facebook developer team on their [Facebook group](http://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/).  I just tested this API call with my own application and it worked just fine with read_mailbox permissions.  Try creating a separate application and trying again.

Comment: It wasnt disabled. I asked Facebook and they emailed me the results

Comment: How did this solve your problem ? Did you create another application?