# Error when reading from mailbox

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0

My application, created today, runs fine when I use it with my account. On any other account however, the following error is sent back as a response:

```
message: "(#298) You must be a developer of the application"
type: "OAuthException"
```

The exact code I'm using to send the request is this:

```
FB.api('/me/threads', {limit: 1000}, function(response){ ....
```

I have found someone experiencing the same problem, but the response he accepted didn't really provide any useful information. ( [Reading over inbox, I get error #298](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394374/reading-over-inbox-i-get-error-298)).

Anyone have a clue on how to solve this? Would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing you have the read_mailbox permission?

Try accessing the `/me/inbox` connection instead?

Facebook tells you (from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/thread/):

> Please note: We are in the process of making the new messages system
>   available to all users, at which point this API will replace the
>   /inbox/ Graph API endpoint. We are providing early access to this API
>   for registered developer accounts only until the new messaging system
>   is broadly available. You should use the /inbox endpoint for
>   production applications at the current time.

That is, only the current apps developers will be able to use the `threads`-connection for now (but it will be available later).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your other account doesn't have a developer license/flag/attribute, thus failing the authentication check.

Comment: Yes, that must be correct. But how can I allow anyone to access my application?